# Is there a simple query that will solve this dilemma?

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on a personal project/development here. Took a job with starfleet command querying our fleet inventory of starships. I want to query the Features table and return a list of starshipId's that match a list of features. Best I've come up with is a query that will return any one match. However I want to return starshipid for starships that have every feature listed in query. Please see picture.

What I've tried so far:

```sql
select distinct starshipid
from features
where description in ('Teleporation', 'Warp Speed')
```

I'm looking for a query that will only return starshipid: 1000

[image: Data sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to get only those startshipid's having all description mentioned in IN clause then use count and distinct in HAVING clause. Your query will be like below:

```
SELECT STARSHIPID
FROM FEATURES
WHERE DESCRIPTION IN ('TELEPORATION', 'WARP SPEED')
GROUP BY STARSHIPID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT DESCRIPTION) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close. If you know that conditions do not overlap, you can just count them

```
select starshipid
from features
where description in ('Teleporation', 'Warp Speed')
group by starshipid
having count(*) = 2
```

it should be fine for your scenario, just beware more complicated queries. Imagine this table

| FeatureId | StarshipId | Decription |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1000 | Steel shield enhanced |
| 2 | 1000 | Laser shield |

```
select starshipid
from features
where description like '%shield%' or description like '%warp%'
group by starshipid
having count(*) = 2
```

it would return this ship, even though the warp condition is not fulfilled, because the shield condition is met in two features.

And it would not return this ship

```
select starshipid
from features
where description like '%steel%' or description like '%enhanced%'
group by starshipid
having count(*) = 2
```

because even though all conditions are fulfilled, it is just one feature

Comment: You're a genius. It worked. I'm not sure what you mean by conditions do not overlap though?