# MySQL Query to find all subscriptions to a tag where all values match

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm struggling to articulate what I'm trying to achieve.

I have a product which can be assigned many tags, I then have a subscription table which holds the productID and the tagID.

I'd like to search the subscription table in the most efficient way to see if a product is subscribed to ALL tags (not ANYthat I provide).

I've tried many things including this:

```
SELECT 

productID

FROM productTagSubscription

WHERE tagID IN ( 'id1', 'id2', 'id3', 'id4');
```

So the product has to be subscribed to all 4 ID's as 4 rows in the subscription table

This is then pulling back any records for ANY id, which isn't what I'm trying to achieve - any advice appreciated!!

Table Structure:
[image]

**Expected Output**
My expected output when passing all 3 or 4 tagID's into the table would give me a list of products that all subscribe to all tags provided.

Comment: it seems you can use distinct count. Share sample data script and table script and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Amit - using DISTINCT COUNT will give me what result? I'm not sure I'm understanding your solution.

Comment: your question has _if a product is subscribed to ALL tags (not ANYthat I provide)._ For this distinct count may be required. but without sample data scripts and expected output from the sample data, no one can help

Comment: Sample data scripts? I take it that's not the query I'm using which I've posted?

Comment: Please check if the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746800/is-there-a-simple-query-that-will-solve-this-dilemma/67748471#67748471) helps you. I think it is same.

Comment: Ok this works - as long as I change the COUNT number to match the number of tags I'm looking for - thank you for all your help.

Comment: if this works, please upvote solution at that link.

Answer (score 1):

You can count the diferent `tagID` for each product.

```
SELECT productID
FROM productTagSubscription
GROUP BY productID
HAVING COUNT(tagID) = 4; /* total amount of tags */
```

In many pivot tables, you can find a unique pair key, in this case between (productID, tagID), if that's not the case make sure `tagID` are `DISCTINCT`.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISCTINCT(tagID)) = 4;
```

> as long as I change the COUNT number to match the number of tags I'm looking for

If you want to avoid the number, assuming that all tags are been used in one or another product.

```
HAVING COUNT(DISCTINCT(tagID)) = (
    SELECT MAX(DISCTINCT(tagID))
    FROM productTagSubscription 
);

HAVING COUNT(DISCTINCT(tagID)) = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tags
);
```

Comment: Thanks Juan - that's great and pretty much the same solution Amit offered.